# Type inference of KeyValuePair constructor - already in .NET?

Tags: c#

I'm currently using...

```
public static class KeyValuePairFactory {
    public static KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> Create<TKey, TValue>(
        TKey key,
        TValue value
    ) {
        return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value);
    }
}
```

...so instead of...

```
var pair = new KeyValuePair<MyVeryUnwieldyType1, MyVeryUnwieldyType2>(
    new MyVeryUnwieldyType1(),
    new MyVeryUnwieldyType2()
);
```

...I can avoid repeating types and simply:

```
var pair = KeyValuePairFactory.Create(
    new MyVeryUnwieldyType1(),
    new MyVeryUnwieldyType2()
);
```

Am I reinventing the wheel and reimplementing something that is already available in .NET Framework?

Comment: You can make it even shorter by making the factory method an extension method and calling it WithValue(this T key, V value). Then you can just do: var kvp = myKey.WithValue(myValue);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on whether you definitely want `KeyValuePair`. I don't know that there's anything for `KeyValuePair`, but it *does* exist on `Tuple`, via [`Tuple.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee835388):

```
Tuple<int, int> foo = Tuple.Create(10, 20);
```

Personally I rarely find myself *creating* `KeyValuePair` values directly - I find it's more common to be consuming them as part of using LINQ to Objects on a `Dictionary<,>`.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'm aware of that, but there are pieces of code that already expect `KeyValuePair` so that's what I'm stuck with for now. BTW, are you aware of _any_ reason to use `KeyValuePair` over `Tuple` (other than legacy code), when not enumerating over `Dictionary` and such?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: Two potential reasons: `Tuple` is a class, where you may *want* a struct (or vice versa, of course); and `KeyValuePair` describes what you're trying to represent - a key and a value. Just `Tuple<,>` doesn't describe the relationship between the two values.

Comment: OK, cool. I guess I'll keep "reinventing the wheel" for a little while longer. It's a very small wheel after all ;) Thanks again.